# jQuery doesn't recognize an attribute from a <a> tag

Tags: jquery

I have this sort of a link:

```
<a class="image_button" data-problem_id="157"  style="display: inline;" href="#"><span>See Solutions Members Have Already Suggested</span></a>
```

and then I try to get the id like this:

```
var problem_id = $(this).attr("data-problem_id");
```

but it ends up being undefined. Any idea why? In other cases I did what seems to be exactly this, and I was able to get the problem_id

Thanks!

Comment: Works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/7U3vA/. I'm guessing the problem is somewhere else in your code (maybe `this` is not the object you think it is).

Comment: @Alxandr interesting point. What else could this be? Here is a url to an example page http://www.problemio.com/problems/problem.php?problem_id=157

Comment: In what scope are you calling $(this)? 
This seems to be the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found your error, though it's outside the scope of your problem. The point is, the `this` is a div, and not your button. How you change this you need to see for yourself. You can either reassign the click (instead of `$("#div_id").live('click', blabla);` do `$("#button_id").live('click', blabla);`, or you can run the check on the click target.

This would look something like:

```
$('#div_id').live('click', function(evt) {
    var btn = $(evt.target).closest('a');
    var data_thingy = btn.data('data_thingy');
});
```

**[Edit]**
You can btw also do this: `$('#div_id a').live('click', blabla)`. The `this`-object will then be the actual button.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can use:

```
$(this).data("problem_id");
```

to access data attributes.

Comment: In that case, try `console.log(this)` and see what shows up in the console. Perhaps you're using `this` wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that $(this) is not the hyperlink object that you think it is. You could go to Console.log and see what the object really is. Also have you tried using:

```
var problem_id = $('.image_button').attr('data-problem_id');
```